# Is there closed form for eigenvalues of this matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

What is nice closed expression for determinant and eigenvalues of
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&\dots&m\\
m&1&\dots&m-1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
2&3&\dots&1
\end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: It looks like a circulant matrix. It has an eigensystem where eigenvalues are DFT coefficients and eigenvectors are the basis functions. So determinant will be product of coefficients of FFT of the first row.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: That is well known but not sure if it yields closed expressions.

Comment: Of course it does. It is a popular exercise for first timer transform theory students to calculate closed expression for the Fourier coefficients of a linear function. For signal engineers it is the famous "sawtooth" wave shape.

Comment: the eigenvalues are $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ and $\frac{m}{e^{\frac{2\pi ji}{m}}-1}$ for $j = 1,\ldots,m-1$. The determinant is $\frac{(-m)^{m-1}(m+1)}{2}$. For a derivation of the determinant, see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2751920/59379) of a related question.